# Assigning a value to a variable at the same time an expression is evaluated. Multiple statements on the same expression line?

Tags: variables, ssrs-2008, expression, reporting-services

We have a report that contains a table that prints details lines and part of the tablix is a total field called TextboxSubTotal.

Also in this report is a variable called SubTotal.

Can you tell us how to assign the value from TextboxSubTotal to SubTotal when the TextboxSubTotal gets a value?

I'm assuming it needs to be done as part of the expression that assigns the value to TextboxSubTotal.

So far the expression is:

```
=Sum(Fields!LineTotal.Value)
```

Is there a way to put an assignment statement on the same line as the expression?